# unittest and QThread - signal transmission

Tags: pyqt, python-unittest

I am trying to test a method in a Qt.QThread using unittest.

```
import sys
import unittest
from PyQt4 import Qt, QtCore, QtGui

class ConnectionBox(QtCore.QObject):
    """
    a class to test any signal emition
    """
    def __init__(self, *args):
        apply(QtCore.QObject.__init__,(self,)+args)
        self.signalArrived=0
        self.args=[]

    def slotSlot(self, *args):
        self.signalArrived=1
        self.args = args


class ThreadToTest(QtCore.QThread):
    """
    the thread to test
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThreadToTest, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("signalEmited()"))


class TestSignalEmition(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    the test case
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.connectionBox = ConnectionBox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.app = None
        self.connectionBox = None

    def testThread(self):
        self.thread = ThreadToTest()
        self.app.connect(self.thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("signalEmited()"), self.connectionBox.slotSlot)
        self.thread.start()
        self.assertEqual(self.connectionBox.signalArrived, 1)
        self.thread.quit()


def suite():
    testSuite=unittest.makeSuite(TestSignalEmition)
    return testSuite


def main():
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

What is supposed to happen :

1. The thread start
2. The thread emit a signal
3. The signal is transmitted to the slotSlot method
4. signalArrived is set to 1

But step 3 is not made.
Is it related to unittest or QThread  ?

Thanks for your inputs

(edit for easier way too see the result)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

You can't emit a signal without first defining it.  You need to create the signal on the `QThread` first for it to emit it.  Also, you should really be using the new-style signal/slot syntax.

```
class ThreadToTest(QtCore.QThread):
    signalToEmit = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        self.signalToEmit.emit()
```

Also, signals and slots (and all other event processing) only happen within a running `QApplication` event loop.  The event loop doesn't start until you run `app.exec_()`, which you're not doing.

I don't think it's really possible to test PyQt this way using the standard `unittest` framework.  You may want to look into the [`QTest`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtest.html) module.